# Retrieve subsequent rows when condition is met from two different columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with data that looks like this:

```
  Part Number Vendor Name Position Repair
          123         ABC        1      2
           NA        <NA>        2      4
           NA        <NA>        3      1
           NA        <NA>        4      5
           NA        <NA>        5      6
           NA        <NA>        6      3
          123         XYZ        1      4
           NA        <NA>        2      5
           NA        <NA>        3      7
           NA        <NA>        4      1
           NA        <NA>        5      2
           NA        <NA>        6      3
           NA        <NA>        7      6
```

I have a part number and vendor name grouped. Whenever position column > 3 and Repair ==1, retrieve subsequent rows.

Suppose in the given example for Part number =123 and vendor name=ABC, the repair==1 is at third position [position=3]-> All the rows that belong to part=123 and vendor name =ABC should be excluded.

Part=123 and vendor name=XYZ, the repair ==1 is at the fourth position. So retrieve 4th,5th,6th and 7th rows.

Condition to be considered is consider rows where Position >3 and Repair ==1, retrieve all subsequent rows.

Sample data:

```
Input <- structure(list(`Part Number` = c(123, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 123, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Vendor Name` = c("ABC", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "XYZ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Position = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Repair = c(2, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4, 
5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6)), .Names = c("Part Number", "Vendor Name", "Position", 
"Repair"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I've tried the following but it hasn't resulted in what I wanted:

```
output_table <- Input %>% group_by(`Part Number`,`Vendor Name`) %>% 
mutate(rn=row_number()) %>% filter(rn>=which(pivot$Repair==1)) #Here I'm able to filter subsequent rows where repair==1 but how to exclude the rows which doesn't fall under the mentioned conditions.

output_table <- Input[Input$Position >3 & Input$Repair==1,] # gives me rows matching the condition but I need subsequent rows once the condition is met
```

Comment: Is your input structure a `data.frame`? What you provided here is incomplete. What is `sample` if you named your first structure `Input`? It makes it a lot easier if the data and code you provide are something can use "as-is". (Further, you define names `Part Name` and `Vendor Name` but your grouping is on `Part Number` and `Vendor name` (not the case).)

Comment: Sorry for  the mistakes. I have corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dplyr and tidyr you can do this as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Input %>% 
  fill(`Part Number`, `Vendor Name`) %>%   # fill down missing values
  group_by(`Part Number`, `Vendor Name`) %>%   # group by `Part Number` & `Vendor Name`
  filter( cumsum(Position>3 & Repair==1) >= 1)   # select only rows where the cumulative sum of true/false condition >= 1
```

Output for that should be what you are looking for:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  `Part Number` `Vendor Name` Position Repair
          <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>
1           123 XYZ                  4      1
2           123 XYZ                  5      2
3           123 XYZ                  6      3
4           123 XYZ                  7      6
```

Comment: This just gives me one row when position >3 and repair==1 row. But i need subsequent rows as well once the condition is met

Comment: If you run the code from my answer it will give you all the rows you are looking for:  The cumsum gives you the cumulative sum of 1 as soon as that criteria is met - i.e. so all rows after are returned as well.  I'll put the output at the end of the answer to show you.

Comment: If it helps note `(Position>3 & Repair ==1)` evaluates as FALSE or TRUE:  When you sum: FALSE = 0 and TRUE = 1. So `cumsum(...) >= 1` is checking the running sum of that logical test. It only takes one match before the cumsum is always >=1

Comment: I've updated to include group_by which was needed to evaluate each ( `Part Number` +`Vendor Name`) group separately.

Comment: Yes i had actually missed the update ! Thank u. Its working now

Answer (score 2):

Your format seems like it is geared towards *presentation* (reports) vice for data processing. Any processing like this should really be done before you do things like remove repeating rows for visual-grouping.

Ultimately, the only part you need here within `group_by` is the use of `cumany`. The rest of the mutating code is to accommodate the `NA` fields.

```r
Input %>%
  # assuming order is "safe to assume"
  mutate_at(vars(`Part Number`, `Vendor Name`), zoo::na.locf) %>%
  group_by(`Part Number`,`Vendor Name`) %>%
  filter(cumany(Position > 3 & Repair == 1)) %>%
  # return the first two columns to NA
  mutate(toprow = row_number() == 1L) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(`Part Number`, `Vendor Name`), ~ if_else(toprow, ., .[NA])) %>%
  select(-toprow)
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   `Part Number` `Vendor Name` Position Repair
#           <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1           123 XYZ                  4      1
# 2            NA <NA>                 5      2
# 3            NA <NA>                 6      3
# 4            NA <NA>                 7      6
```

---

If you are doing more processing on the data, I'd suggest you don't undo "dragging the labels down", instead just doing:

```r
Input %>%
  # assuming order is "safe to assume"
  mutate_at(vars(`Part Number`, `Vendor Name`), zoo::na.locf) %>%
  group_by(`Part Number`,`Vendor Name`) %>%
  filter(cumany(Position > 3 & Repair == 1)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   `Part Number` `Vendor Name` Position Repair
#           <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1           123 XYZ                  4      1
# 2           123 XYZ                  5      2
# 3           123 XYZ                  6      3
# 4           123 XYZ                  7      6
```

Comment: Thats really a quick reply.Much Appreciated!! Well the real data doesn’t have Na’s at all. It will have part number and vendor name filled in.

Comment: Two points: (1) *"the real data doesn't have Na's at all"* ... why did you provide data like that? ***Please*** provide *representative* data in questions, the presence of NAs added an unnecessary fixing-step to both answers. (2) I used `cumany(...)` which is faster than and effectively equivalent to `cumsum(...)>0`, `tidyr::fill` and `zoo::na.locf` do the same thing (even though you didn't really need it), and this answer was correct over 2 hours prior, but the other answer is "correct"? I truly don't care about the points, but courtesy is courtesy.

Comment: i’m very sorry for providing much data. I’m a newbie to this concepts and i didn’t know the Na’s would cause so much trouble. I know your answer was 100% correct but it took me some time to understand the code.